# After installing the awslocal CLI with pip3, I am seeing this in my terminal while checking the CLI options: zsh: command not found: awslocal

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I am trying to install the awslocal CLI tool with pip3.

I have ran the command:

```
pip3 install awscli-local --user
```

I am trying to see the what CLI options there are and have run the command

```
awslocal
```

I am getting this response

```
zsh: command not found: awslocal
```

I am not sure what other steps I am missing

Comment: What environment are you attempting to install awslocal in? Linux, windows, WSL, gitbash?

Comment: @Dent7777 with zsh message, this can be only Mac...

Comment: Ah, I'm not familiar with Macs.

Answer (score 5):

**Run the command**

`sudo pip3 install awscli-local`

You will be asked for your system password, please provide that.

Now, command will install required things, your next screen will be like :-

```
Collecting awscli-local
Downloading awscli-local-0.21.tar.gz (11 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
```

You can check the status after running successfully, by running below command.

`awslocal --version`

Answer (score 3):

Run the command:

```
pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user
```

and watch closely where the aws cli tool gets installed, you can see the path on terminal log, in my case I got something like this:

```
awscli in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages
```

Now you should add to your .bash_profile the same path but on the bin folder(removing from the lib path and instead put your bin path) like this:

```
export PATH=/Users/your.user.name/Library/Python/3.8/bin/:$PATH
```

Comment: The question is about `awslocal` that should be provided by `localstack` : https://github.com/localstack/localstack#example